# Proper way to query for a Has One Relationship

Tags: go, go-gorm

If I am looking for the Person with Credit Card Number `CreditCardNumber` Is this the proper way to do it?

```golang
type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name            string
    CreditCard CreditCard 
}

type CreditCard struct {
    gorm.Model
    PersonID       *uint
    Number string
}

database.dbClient.
   Preload("CreditCard").
   Where("credit_card.number = ?", CreditCardNumber).
   Joins("left join credit_cards on person.id = credit_card.person_id AND credit_card.deleted_at is NULL").
   First(&Person)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
db.Preload("Person").Find(&CreditCard)
```

Also I don't think PersonID should be a pointer.

Comment: Unscoped seems to return all the records including the deleted ones.
I want to only retrieve the ones that have not been deleted. That is why I put the deleted_at is null.
When i looked at the debug logs for this. The join looked like it was returning rows that were soft deleted.